# Scheduled Notifications don't work when I pass the id attribute with uuidv4()

Tags: react-native, javascript-objects, uuid, localnotification, react-native-push-notification

Please I would love you all to assist me solve this bug I've been on since last night with react-native-push-notification.
I've been trying to send a push notification using the `PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule()` function. The code works perfectly until I add the id attribute to the notification object.
Here's an example of when the code works:

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
        channelId: "channel-id",
        title: `Hi there ${fullName}!`,
        message: `You've Got A To-Do "${todoInfo.title}" Now!`,
        date: new Date(todoInfo.dateDue),
        allowWhileIdle: true,
      });
```

It also works when I do this:

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
        channelId: "channel-id",
        title: `Hi there ${fullName}!`,
        message: `You've Got A To-Do "${todoInfo.title}" Now!`,
        date: new Date(todoInfo.dateDue),
        id: 555,
        allowWhileIdle: true,
      });
```

But doesn't work when I use a library to generate a unique id so that I can cancel the notification afterwards; example code here:

```
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

// Some other code here

PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
        channelId: "channel-id",
        title: `Hi there ${fullName}!`,
        message: `You've Got A To-Do "${todoInfo.title}" Now!`,
        date: new Date(todoInfo.dateDue),
        id: uuidv4(),
        allowWhileIdle: true,
      });
```

Please, is there a way I can get past this?

I tried using a random id generator like uuid and it didn't work.
When I pass the id hardcoded, it works.
I'm expecting a notification to show up on my app.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#channel-management-android), the notification won't work until the Channel is created:

`"channel-id"` is the default created `channelId` and therefore notifications work when using it in the `channelId`

## Create a local Channel ID:

you have to hard code the notification channel ID in **AndroidMainfest.xml**

```
  <meta-data
  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.default_notification_channel_id"
  android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

For remote Firebase Cloud Messenger Notifications refer to [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

## Checking Channel Exists & Listing them

Here is the code [from the documentation](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#list-channels) to check for channels & list out the available channels for notifications

```js
PushNotification.getChannels(function (channel_ids) {
  console.log(channel_ids); // ['channel_id_1']
});
```

> Take note that channel ID is not the same as a unique-id of the notification, so trying to use it with uuid is not it's supposed usage